# Dart - secret key generation based on elliptic curve 25519

Tags: dart, flutter, diffie-hellman, ed25519

I am looking for a dart package in order to implement key exchange protocol (Elliptic-curve Diffie–Hellman) in a Flutter application. So the flow will be like this:

- app generates a key pair during login and sends the public key to
  server (so a new key pair is generated for every login)
- server sends back its public key that it just generated
- app generates a secret key from its private key and server's public
  key
- app includes the hmac of all subsequent messages sent to the server

I tried using the [ed25519_dart package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/ed25519_dart) for the key generation, but it doesn't work. My app doesn't even start due to `integer literal can't be represented in 64 bits` error, which is also pointed out by the dart analyzer.

I also took a look at [pointycastle](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pointycastle), but it doesn't seem to support Diffie–Hellman.

The [Diffie–Hellman package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dh) also doesn't work for me. Provided example throws this exception in the first line:

```
FormatException: Invalid radix-16 number
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC90FDAA22168C234C4C6628B80DC1CD129024E088A67CC74020BBEA63B1...
```

Any idea how I could achieve what I want to do in a Flutter application?

Comment: That probably needs to be updated to Dart 2

Comment: That meaning the ed25519_dart package?

Comment: Yes I was referring to this package. Sorry. Probably the same for the other 2.

Comment: Thanks, I will create issues for them on GitHub - but not sure if these libraries are still maintained. I hope there is some other package that does the job as I wouldn't want to implement my custom solution (especially when it comes to crypto business).

Comment: Crypto could use some boost :-/

Answer (score 0):

The error I am assuming is connected to BigNum and Dart 2. Pointy Castle has a branch on GitHub where they are switching to Dart 2.0.

Here are some ways you could get a keypair:

- Use a native SDK (Java, Kotlin, or C++) and use a platform channel
- Use the pointy castle Dart 2.0 branch
- Try flutter_sodium package. It works with Dart 2 but is a work in progress.

Hopefully, this helps. I am trying to figure out the best way as well!

Comment: Thanks, I already looked into pointy castle. I tried using their `ECKeyGenerator`, but it's not clear to me with which `CipherParameters` it should be initialized. Also, I didn't see any function for generating a secret key from my private key and server's public key. I will look into flutter_sodium as well.